# How to deploy website using Git?

Tags: git, deployment, git-push

I want to use Git to deploy my local Laravel website to my server. I have been reading tutorials on how to do this, but they all mention writing some `post-receive` web-hook, which me being very new to Git, don't fully understand.

Could someone explain to me, why using `git push` to my `public_html` is not enough? I tried it but it did not copy any of my website files so I am guessing I am missing something here (probably web-hooks). Why does not `git push` copy everything from my local directory on to my server?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I have been following this tutorial:

https://blog.sebduggan.com/2012/03/13/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/

Why do we need a web-hook for the server to checkout the repo we push our changes to into my web root? Why cant we just submit our changes directly to the web root?

Comment: https://devdocs.io/git/githooks

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git hooks are just some executable doing anything you wrote in a bash script. What you probably missing is to add a hook to move to the version you just pushed. This simply is a bash script which will call `git checkout -f` to update that directory. More information [here](https://mikeeverhart.net/2013/01/using-git-to-deploy-code/)

**UPDATE**

If you just don't want to use hooks, you can achieve this another way. You can create a center repository like gitlab or github then push your changes there. Then clone that project in your server and instead of pushing changes to server you should pull changes from server.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Could you see my updated question?

Comment: You are pushing the changes to that folder BUT, this data is in background (.git folder) your HEAD of that git folder is still on the previous version. You will add the hook to tell git to move to the latest version which you just pushed

Comment: Okay, got that thanks. One more thing, I still don't get: why is not it enough to make a git repo as my web root, and just push changes there with git push?

Comment: Because git's structure is like this. When you push to a repository you will just push the patches (changes) of files to it and it will store them in the `.git` folder in the root. The files that you are seeing will be constructed from these patches (This way it is possible to checkout to previous versions while having the newer ones as well).

Comment: Note that git will get that you just pushed a new patch but does not know if you actually want to update your current files with this patch. So it will make possible for you to be notified about the events and you can do whatever you want in case of those events using hooks.

Comment: Ohh I get it now, thank you so much!! If I would have all my website files on the server and an exact copy of the server locally, if I would change a line of code locally, would git push be enough (because I only want to push that one line of code)?

Comment: No you still need to use hooks. It does not matter how much have been changed. Git should be ordered to move your working directory up to your last version

Comment: Also, if you don't want to use hooks, I updated my answer, take a look

Comment: @BalázsVincze If your question has been answered how about mark it as answer?